Can I Have Screen Lock Without Monitor Power Down? (Ubuntu 24.04)
I recently performed a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 (LTS).  Overall, things have gone smoothly.  However, I noticed the following problem:
In Settings -> Power I change "Power Saving -> Screen Blank" to Never.  I noticed this also has the effect of changing :
Privacy & Security -> Screen Lock -> Blank Screen Delay to Never also.
If I understand correctly, default Ubuntu has the following components:
GNOME 46
GDM3
Wayland
After some research, there seems to be no combination of settings, given these three features, that will allow me to do what I want, which is, disable the monitor power off/standby feature completely, but I still want the screen to lock after a certain period of time and switch to the lock screen (Clock, date, "press any key to login", etc).
I am not an expert on display/screen things in Linux.  I have run into a similar issue with various distros before and have always found a setting or some utility I could install that would fix it.
Is this possible with 24.04?
Thank you,
K

With older versions of ubuntu, I was using "No Screen Blank" by croisebeck.
It doesn't work with gnome > 42
"Unblank" by xiaoguang_wang does the trick for ubuntu 24 using gnome 46.
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1414/unblank/
